# AWS CloudFormation ContainerDefinitions Secrets assigning full SecretString for each variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager

I want to populate environment variables with credentials stored in a secrets manager, but the ENV variables in the instantiated task have not the expected values, but a assigned with the full `SecretString`.

The definition looks as specified in the documentation:

```
...
Parameters:
  ...
  SecretARN:
    Type: String
    Description: ARN of the secrets manager

MyTask:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ...
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: 'my-task'
          ...
          Secrets:
            - Name: PASSWORD
              ValueFrom: !Ref SecretARN
            - Name: USERNAME
              ValueFrom: !Ref SecretARN
...
```

The secret's `SecretString` looks like this:

```
{
    "PASSWORD": "v3r1s3cr3t",
    "USERNAME": "johndoe"
}
```

In the app or task, when I execute `env`, the output prints like this:

```
PASSWORD='{ "PASSWORD": "v3r1s3cr3t", "USERNAME": "johndoe" }'
USERNAME='{ "PASSWORD": "v3r1s3cr3t", "USERNAME": "johndoe" }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are 3 parts to a Secrets Manager secret:

- The *Secret's Name or Label* e.g. PROD_DB_CREDS
- One or more *Secret's Keys* e.g. DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD
- And the actual *Secret Values* for the keys.

When you use the ARN to access PROD_DB_CREDS, you will get a JSON object back with the keys and the values:

```
{
  "DB_USERNAME": 'my-username',
  "DB_PASSWORD": 'my-password'
}
```

Rather than paste an ARN into the parameters section of your CloudFormation templates, you can access the secret values using a resolver (as in these docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-secretsmanager)

You would then resolve the above secret values in your CloudFormation template using:

```
MyTask:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ...
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: 'my-task'
          ...
          Secrets:
            - Name: PASSWORD
              ValueFrom: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:PROD_DB_CREDS:SecretString:DB_PASSWORD}}'
            - Name: USERNAME
              ValueFrom: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:PROD_DB_CREDS:SecretString:DB_USERNAME}}'
...
```

Your CloudFormation service role will need the correct permissions to access the secret.

Comment: Thx @lemming, your comment was quite helpful. However, it was not exactly working as you described. Resolving the secret's key in `.Secrets[x].ValueFrom` only seems to result in specifing the `ValueFrom` value with the secret value which, because in this template specification Cloudformation seems to try to extract the "value from _a concrete secret value_" which is not what I want.

BUT, I moved the resolving element to the `Environment:` section and used `Value` instead of `ValueFrom` and not I can instantiate it right.

Could you confirm that it makes sense what I did?

Comment: If you confirm and I update your answer, I can edit your answer as the correct one ;)

Comment: Hi @TillKolter. I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "CloudFormation seems to try to extract the value from a *concrete secret value*". But yes, please feel free to edit my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Lets say I would have a secret `PASSWORD=$3C&et` with a template like this:

```
Secrets:
            - Name: PASSWORD
              ValueFrom: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:PROD_DB_CREDS:SecretString:DB_PASSWORD}}'

```

Then this would translate after resolution to:

```
Secrets:
            - Name: PASSWORD
              ValueFrom: '$3C&et'
```

This resulted – at least in my setup – in validation errors, because Cloudformation analyzes the `ValueFrom` value as a key and keys are supposed to be `[a-zA-z0-9.-:]`. My conclusion was to put it in `Environment` and it worked.

Comment: Making it work does not always mean that it was done right – in my experience in a lot of cases the opposite. A very critical aspect which I see with my solution is that the secrets would now be exposed as plaintext in the template description.

Comment: @TillKolter you are correct about moving it to `Environment` but note that it's not the same behavior. With `Environment`, the secret gets resolved only once during CloudFormation deploy and it's then available in clear text in your task definition. With `Secrets`, the secrets gets resolved at each container startup and is not visible in your task definition. Currently if you want to use secrets you will have to JSON parse it in your app. See https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/385

Comment: @lemming the example you have provided for ContainerDefinitions is still wrong. The Secrets -> ValueFrom looks for ARN, the dynamic value as provided '{{resolve:secretsmanager:SECRET_NAME}}' does not work in case of AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition -> ContainerDefinitions.