# CDK - Iterate over a SecretManager keys

Tags: node.js, express, aws-cdk

Let's say I have an Express application that makes calls to a third-party API on behalf of customer companies that use the system. The application includes the company's API key in the request, which must be in the environment under the name `${COMPANY_ID}-key`.

The function that makes the call looks like this:

```
function makeCall(companyId, data) {
    const apiKey = process.env[`${companyId}-key`]
    if(!apiKey) throw new Error("Missing API key for company " + companyId)
    performCall(companyId, apiKey, data)
```

I want to deploy this application using CDK. The stack's secrets look like this:

```
 const ecsApplicationStack = new EcsApplicationStackFactory(
      this,
      {
        containerFolder: resolve(__dirname, `..`, `..`),
        stackName: SERVICE.name,
        secrets: {
          DB_CONN_URL: `{STAGE}/myapp/db:conn-url`,
          // here I need to add all the keys `${COMPANY_ID}-key`
        },
      // ...
)
```

Assuming all API keys for the companies are listed in a secret manager, is there a way I can access all keys inside of it and spread them into the `secrets` objects of the app stack?

Comment: Can't you get the secrets at runtime?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS CloudFormation ContainerDefinitions Secrets assigning full SecretString for each variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213974/aws-cloudformation-containerdefinitions-secrets-assigning-full-secretstring-for)